# 8 8's make 1000

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, arithmetic

Print the following output of a happy coincidence addition pattern:

```
   8
   8
   8
  88
+888
----
1000
```

Rules:

- No leading spaces except the ones already present
- There can be a trailing newline
- `+` sign needs to be displayed
- Order of parcels needs to be the same

No winner. It is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) per language.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want us to print? `1000`? `8+8+8+88+888=1000`?

Comment: I think he wants the entire equation as-is.

Comment: @Okx: That is not valid. I want a *vertical* output ypsis verbis of what I posted.

Comment: Ah, I got confused by the lack of the tag [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: I downvoted this challenge for the following reason: The output is far too short (in my opinion) for a KC challenge, and doesn't have a great pattern either. This doesn't leave too much place for clever compression, and hardcoding is most likely the golfiest way to solve it (in most languages).

Comment: I upvoted because with answers getting below the size of the plain output (34 bytes), there obviously *are* some "clever" ways.

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```powershell
,'   8'*3+"  88
+888"+'-'*4+1e3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0ddQUHBQl3LWFsJSFtwaVtYWChpq@uqa5loG6Ya//8PAA)

Five bytes shorter than [printing the string as-is](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11BQcGCC5mwsODStgASukDAZWhgYKD@/z8A), <s>but still not very golfy.</s> now getting to be golfy.

Constructs an array of 3x `'   8'` (saving a byte), then array-concatenates the remaining items, with `'-'*4` saving a byte. The other byte savings comes from using `1e3` in place of `1000`.

Comment: You can replace all `+` on line breaks. This will not change the length. Only for fun.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
Ｇ↑↑↓↙³8←→⟦+⁴Ｉφ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT9Pwyq0QEcBQrjkl@dBKZ/UtBIdBWMdBSULJU1rLt/8slQNK5AgkBNQlJlXomEVlJmeAVQTraStpKNgoqPgnFhcopGmGatp/f//f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｇ↑↑↓↙³          Draw a polygon implicitly closing the path
      8         Filled with the string 8
       ←        Move left one character
          +     Literal string +
           ⁴    Integer 4 (prints as ----)
             φ  Predefined variable 1000
            Ｉ   Cast to string
         ⟦      Wrap in array (implicit ⟧)
        →       Override ← print direction
                Implicitly print one per line
```

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 35 bytes

```
printf %4s\\n {,,,8,+88}8 ---- 1000
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUHVpDgmJk@hWkdHx0JH28Ki1kJBFwgUDA0MDP7/BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
print"   8\n"*3+"  88\n+888\n----\n1000"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69ESUFBwSImT0nLWBvItAAytS1ApC4QxOQZGhgYKP3/DwA)

Comment: +2 bytes if you make it Python 3 compatible, but otherwise you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [<s>57</s>](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPIdpCBwwtdNS1LSws1HXUdYFAXcfQwMAg1opLoaAoM69EQ13VpFhdQVUhU/P/fwA) [<s>52</s>](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITMv2kIHDC101LUtLCzUddR1gUBdx9DAwCDWqqAoM69EQ13VpFhdNVPz/38A) [<s>51</s>](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPwUIHDC101LUtLCzUddR1gUBdx9DAwMCqoCgzr0RDXdWkWF01U/P/fwA) 50 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

-1 byte thanks to Dennis.

-1 byte again, thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

```python
for i in 8,8,8,88,'+888','-'*4,1000:print('%4s'%i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPwUIHDC101LUtLCzUddR11bVMdAwNDAysCooy80o01FVNitVVMzX//wcA)

Comment: *Ahum* Hardcoded output is [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ11BQcEiJg@VtACS2hYgUhcIYvIMDQwM1DX//wcA)..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Huh, that’s already my answer :-)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh, oops.. Didn't notice there was another Python answer. Yours is even shorter by using `print"..."` instead of `print('...')`, though. :) I'll delete my comment above in that case.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen because that was already posted for Py2 I didn’t want to steal it ;)  Besides, simply printing hard-coded is... boring?  Almost like a cop-out so I didn’t take that approach :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Keep in mind though that Python 2 and Python 3 are their own languages, in a sense, so there can be two different approaches :)

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
≥č*xi«∙tν↔β⁸‘4n
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMjY1JXUwMTBEKnhpJUFCJXUyMjE5dCV1MDNCRCV1MjE5NCV1MDNCMiV1MjA3OCV1MjAxODRu) - simply    `8   8   8  88+888----1000` compressed, then split to line lengths of 4

<s>20</s> 19 byte non-compression based method:

```
8³'E■888+⁰§o┌4*LM*⁰
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=OCVCMyUyN0UldTI1QTA4ODgrJXUyMDcwJUE3byV1MjUwQzQqTE0qJXUyMDcw)

```
8                    push 8
 ³                   triplicate the 8
  'E                 push 88
    ■888+            push "888+"
         ⁰           wrap those in an array
          §          reverse horizontally, padding with spaces
           o         output that
            ┌4*      push "-"*4
               LM*   push 100*10
                  ⁰  wrap those two in an array, outputting both
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Riley

```
8ÐÐ«D„8+«'-4×₄R).Bí»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v8wNWFiMWX//zjDkMOQwqtE4oCeOCvCqyctNMOX4oKEUikuQsOtwrv//w)

Comment: [`8ÐÐ«D„8+«'-4×₄R).Bí»`](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v8wNWFiMWX//zjDkMOQwqtE4oCeOCvCqyctNMOX4oKEUikuQsOtwrv//w) saves a byte

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 107 bytes

```
++++++++[>+++++>+>+++++++>++++<<<<-]>+++++>++<<+++[->>>>...<.<.<<]>>>>..<..<.<--.>>...<.<++....>.<++++.-...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwqi7cCUnbYdVABM2wCBbixMCsgFqdS1AwI9PT0bELSJhfBswHxdXT2YlLY2kNazAzGATF0g@/9/AA)

### Explanation

```
++++++++[>+++++>+>+++++++>++++<<<<-]>+++++>++<<+++
TAPE:
>V_LOOP< C_DASH C_NL C_EIGHT C_SPACE
003      045    010  056     032

~~~OUTPUT SECTION~~~
V_LOOP TIMES DO                     [-
    PRINT C_SPACE x 3                 >>>> ...
    PRINT C_EIGHT                     <.
    PRINT C_NL                        <.
                                    <<]
PRINT C_SPACE x 2                   >>>>..
PRINT C_EIGHT x 2                   <..
PRINT C_NL                          <.
C_DASH = C_DASH MINUS 2 (PLUS SIGN) <--
PRINT PLUS SIGN                     .
PRINT C_EIGHT x 3                   >>...
PRINT C_NL                          <.
PRINT C_DASH x 4                    <++....
PRINT C_EIGHT                       >.
C_DASH = C_DASH PLUS 2 ('1')        <++++
PRINT '1'                           .
C_DASH = C_DASH MINUS 1 ('0')       -
PRINT '0' x 3                       ...
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 23 bytes

```
00000000: 5350 50b0 e042 262c 2cb8 b42d 8084 2e10  SPP..B&,,..-....
00000010: 7019 1a18 1800 00                        p......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcwxDoJAEIXh3lO8ygomb8ZdHSw5AQkncGBDo4kN5182auuXv/5jj3iWbX/Vyp878iUTmUEUJoNdbYEt4YhkK5yeYEUJzNMkMp67TqSX5vQ9aHvcqAP0oQ51Eq0/3vJR6wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 23 bytes

```
3o³ 8òÙhr8òR1³0-Ò-kr+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f92//8zb8KzIDgbw7LDmWhyOMOyUjHCszAbLcOSLWtyK///)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 37 bytes

```
  7 4 $'   8   8   8  88+888----1000'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 44 bytes

```js
a=x=>`   8
`.repeat(3)+`  88
+888
----
1000`

console.log(a())
```

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i5BQUHBgguZsLDg0rYAErpAwGVoYGCQ8L@gKD85tbhYr7gkJb@0RK@8KLMkVSNNQ1PzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 37 bytes

```sed
s:$:   8:p;p
a\  88
a+888
a----
a1000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v9hKxUpBQcHCqsC6gCsxBsiy4ErUtgCRukDAlWhoYGDw/z8A)

I use the `a` command to append text lines to output. For comparison, the trivial solution is to print the hardcoded text like below, 42 bytes. Reduction is 11.9 %.

```sed
c\   8\n   8\n   8\n  88\n+888\n----\n1000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 31 bytes

```
/!/   8
/!!!  88
+888
----
1000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19RX0FBwYJLX1FREUhbcGlbAAldIOAyNDAw@P8fAA)

A measly 3 bytes savings.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 36 bytes

```
?@   8`?A?A?@  88`?@+888`?@----`?z^3
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 45 bytes

```java
v->"   8\n   8\n   8\n  88\n+888\n----\n1000"
```

Boring hard-coded output, but this can't be done any shorter in Java. Just utilizing the repeated part `"   8\n"` is already 52 bytes..
`v->"aaa  88\n+888\n----\n1000".replace("a","   8\n")`

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##VU7BCoMwDL3vK4KnylDcTZDtD@ZlsMvcIavdqKup2FoYw2/vInpZSB4kebz3OgyY2UFR176jNOgcnFHTdwegyavxiVJBvawAFz9qeoEUV6tbCGnF15mH23n0WkINBEeIITslzC8b@seScV8umHE1dCiKIonVKjFMD8MSm1JYLHpOIlbX2x0w3WJ8nFd9biefD/zyhgTlUtBkTLplmuMP)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
|.|:'1-+','0-88888'$~3,4,:7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I79Gr8ZK3VBXW11H3UDXAgTUVeqMdUx0rMz//wcA)

```
                                             0-8   
          '0-88888'$~3,4,:7      Three rows: 0-88   
                                             0-88888
    '1-+',                       "1-+" on top
|.|:                             Rotate counter-clockwise
```

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 66 bytes

```
HAI 1.3
VISIBLE "   8:)   8:)   8:)  88:)+888:)----:)1000"
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8FQz5grzDPY08nHVUFJQUHBwkoTlbQAktoWIFIXCKw0DQ0MDJS4vEM8IpwiXf//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46 bytes</s>41 bytes

```r
cat('   8
   8
   8
  88
+888
----
1000')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRENdQUHBgguZsLDg0rYAErpAwGVoYGCgrvn/PwA)

Thanks to Dennis for golfing off 5 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 104 bytes

```
++[++[<->->->+>++<<<]>-]<<<<...<<<<<<.<-.>>--...<.<.>>...<.<.>>..<..<.>>>.<<...<.>>>++....<<<.<<<--.-...
```

Uses the same technique as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494/70894) genius answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 42 bytes

```
puts "   8
   8
   8
  88
+888
----
1000"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWEFJQUHBgguZsLDg0rYAErpAwGVoYGCgxPX/PwA)

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWEEpuji1RCFVQUlBQcGCSylWJVUlFciy4NK2ABK6QMBlaGBgoMT1/z8A

Comment: Another failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWEFJIbo4tUQhFchQsFCK5VJQSQVjldQYCy5tCwsLLl0g4DI0MDBQ4vr/HwA

Comment: One more failure: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWEFJQUHBQqlWwZgLxrWw4NK2ABK6QMBlaGBgoPT/PwA

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
∩π╚nY╤¼æ♂ç♦d└tä♂&lò
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=efe3c86e59d1ac910b870464c074840b266c95&a=1)

ASCII equivalent:

```
.-+]125E{'8*eN$m+MrVk+m
```

Build the `8`s together with the line below by transposing the string representation of the array `[-8,-88,-88888]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 66 bytes

```
"0001"25*"-":::25*"888+"25*"88  "25*"8 "::25*"8 "::25*"8 "::>:#,_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X8nAwMBQychUS0lXycrKCsSwsLDQVoIwFBQgDAUlqBQKw85KWSfe4f9/AA)